# How to print NAN instead of 0 if one of a column has NAN in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to check the number of time a condition is true for my product in each file but only needs to check when the condition is satisfied AND both the column are populated, so I'm using this code

```
cnt = big_frame.groupby('Symbol').apply(lambda g:((g.A001 > g.A002) & g.A001.notnull() & g.A002.notnull()).sum())
df['Data_Count'] = df.Contract.map(cnt)
```

that checks for the condition and if both the columns are populated and it works fine for me except that when it encounters NAN in any of the columns, it prints 0 in `cnt` and thus later in 'Data_Count' when I map it with `cnt` which is not good for me as I have to calculate percentage later.

So, what I want is to check for `A001` and `A002`, if any of them has NAN in it, it should print NAN in the cnt column and not 0. Thanks

EDIT:

This is my dataset (just the relevant columns I have skipped all the other rows and columns)

```
Symbol   A001   A002
O.U20   0.005   NAN
O.Z20   0.005  0.0025
O.H21   0.005   NAN
O.M21   0.005   NAN
O.U21   0.005   NAN
O.Z21   0.005   1
O.H22   0.005   0.003
O.M22   0.005   0.005  
O.U20   0.005   NAN
O.Z20   0.005  0.0025
O.H21   0.005   NAN
O.M21   0.005   NAN
O.U21   0.005   NAN
O.Z21   0.005   1
O.H22   0.005   0.003
O.M22   0.005   0.005
```

So according to this I want cnt column to be

```
 cnt
 NAN
 2
 NAN
 NAN
 NAN
 0
 2
 0
```

But right now it's printing 0 instead of NAN

```
 0 
 2
 0
 0
 0
 0
 2
 0
```

Comment: Please provide sample data & expected output to improve your chances of getting a response.

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following (in a couple of steps, for clarity):

```
df["cond"] = np.where(df.A001.isna() | df.A002.isna(), np.NaN, df.A001 > df.A002)

def foo(x):
    if x.isna().all():
        return np.NaN
    else: 
        return x.sum()

df.groupby('Symbol')["cond"].apply(foo)
```

The result is:

```
Symbol
O.H21    NaN
O.H22    2.0
O.M21    NaN
O.M22    0.0
O.U20    NaN
O.U21    NaN
O.Z20    2.0
O.Z21    0.0
Name: cond, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace the 0's with Nans with this:

```py
df['Data_Count'].replace(0, np.nan)
```

But you could also do this:

```py
cnt = big_frame.groupby('Symbol').apply(lambda g: True if ((g.A001 > g.A002) & g.A001.notnull() & g.A002.notnull()).sum() else np.nan)
df['Data_Count'] = df.Contract.map(cnt)
```

Comment: No , there will be cases where A001 < A002 and in that case it should print a 0 not NAN

Comment: @hyeri In this case you will need a nested if within your lamdba, I'll figure it and edit my answer

Comment: @hyeri the lambda you could use would be like this : " lambda g: (g.A001 > g.A002).sum() if (g.A001.notnull() & g.A002.notnull()) else np.Nan " but I don't know if pandas would accept something like that, of course.